# urlencode without quote python

Tags: python, url

I wish to use Python's `urllib.parse.urlencode()` method to convert a dict to URL-like params, however, I do not want any quoting of characters, just the `?<...>=<...>&<...>=<...>` logic.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you want a URL that is not properly URL-encoded?

Answer (score 0):

map or dict comprehension will do, no need for urllib.

```py
your_dict = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'snafu'}
"&".join(map(lambda kv: f"{kv[0]}={kv[1]}",your_dict.items()))
```

Will give you string `foo=bar&baz=snafu`